# Iterable without side effect type annotation

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I'm looking for `Iterable` which is able to be iterated without side effect.
For example, I want to annotate the below args `x`:

```
def foo(x: NoSideEffectIterable[int]):
    for i in range(10):
        for xx in x: # x is iterated 10 times here
            print(i*xx)
```

1. `Iterable` is not suited because `x` is iterated more than once
2. `Sequence` is not suited because the order of `x` doesn't matter

How to annotate `x`?

Comment: What do you mean by "consumable"?

Comment: Able to call `next` without side effect

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the exact opposite of what the word "consumable" would usually mean when applied to an iterable.

Comment: Yes, I modified the title and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no annotation for that. It's not a concept the type system can express. `Iterable` is your best bet. If you want to get a bit more restrictive, you can use `Collection`, but while `Iterable` expresses less requirements than you want, `Collection` expresses more.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Iterator[int]`. Iterators in Python are iterables that get consumed after you iterate them over once. Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation. `x` is applied `next` more than once, so I want to annotate it `Iterable without  sideeffect`